Interface to class Design pattern .... Have anyone using Interface to class design pattern
Is there any
Interface To class design pattern.
Currently I'm joining a new company.and their design pattern is
"Interface to Class " Design pattern.
But I don't know any Interface to class design pattern...
Have anyone using Interface to class design pattern...

java.util.List to ArrayList is probably the most common interface to class.

Did you try asking anyone at the company what this meant? They would provide an more authoritative answer and also be quicker to answer. Say you tried searching online for an answer, but didn't find anything. Shows you had the initiative to try and figure stuff out on your own, but aren't afraid to ask questions when you're stuck. I tried googling "Interface to Class" spring-boot and got zero hits. So it's fair to say they're using an obscure name for what it is probably quite a common design pattern.

Interface To class is commonly used pattern specially in JAVA/Spring-Boot as it supports the concept of loosely coupling.In this pattern,

You create a interface with required methods
Create an implementation class which implements the above created interface.
Third step when using the implementation class value.Instead using implementation class use interface.

Below is the simple code to demonstrate the interface to class pattern.
public interface UserMethod {
User getUser();
boolean saveUser(User user);

}
Now create an implementation class for it.
 public class UserDatabase implements UserMethod{
   @Override
    public User getUser() {
       //Do your logic for getting user
    }

    @Override
    public boolean saveUser(User user) {
       //Do logic to save user
    }
}

public class MongoUserDatabase implements UserMethod {
@Override
public User getUser(String id) {
    // MongoDB query to get user
}

@Override
public boolean saveUser(User user) {
    // MongoDB operation to save user
}

}
public class UserService {

    private final UserMethod userMethod;

    public UserService(UserMethod userMethod) {
        this.userMethod = userMethod;
    }

    public User getUser(String id) {
        return userMethod.getUser(id);
    }

    public boolean saveUser(User user) {
        return userMethod.saveUser(user);
    }
}


UserMethod userMethod = new UserDatabase();
UserService userService = new UserService(userMethod);

// After migration
UserMethod userMethod = new MongoUserDatabase();
UserService userService = new UserService(userMethod);

Notice:as in above we created constructor of Interface not implementation class.
What are it's advantages:

Suppose in future we want to use other database to change logic inside the getUser() and saveUser() method or.So only your implementation class code will change without effecting any other code.It provides the concept of loosely coupling.


What's the point of doing this? When there is always an exact 1-to-1 relationship between class and interface, you can just as well use the class directly.

@Sören here is the example in case only one class is implementing the interface.But we can make multiple class implement the same interface.

Thanks for confirming that this pattern as described in this answer is pointless.

@Sören Also useful in case of 1-to -1 relationship.Suppose you are migrating the database from one to another.You would create another class that implements the interface and build the logic there.No need to change other than dependency injection
